# HTML/Javascript/jQuery data from loop for table<tr>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm fairly new to coding and working on a school project here, and am hitting a road block.
I am designed a donut shop report generator that should randomly generate # of donuts needed for production per hour of business, and total based on the variables in my array.
I am able to get my code to generate the needed info in the console.log, but not in the table.
I know that I am trying to uniquely identify column/row positions in the table () but do not know how to do that.
I added the line with the :nth-of-type, as I understand that is the way to identify column and row, but the table is not populated.

Appreciate any help, coaching or advice that might be out there.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <title>Chris Petrick's Donut Shop Chain | Donuts for People Who Hate Donuts</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
console.log ("start");

function Shop(name, minCustHour, maxCustHour, avgDonPerCust, totalHour, displayColumn ) {
 this.name = name;
 this.minCustHour = minCustHour;
 this.maxCustHour = maxCustHour;
 this.avgDonPerCust = avgDonPerCust;
 this.totalHour = totalHour;
 this.totalDonuts = 0;
 this.hourlyDonuts = [];
 this.displayColumn = displayColumn;


 this.donutsPerHour = function(){
  var range = this.maxCustHour - this.minCustHour;
  var avgDonPerHour = Math.floor ((Math.random() * range) + this.minCustHour);
  return avgDonPerHour;
 }
 // =========HOURS FOR LOOP=============
 this.donutsPerDay = function(){
  console.log("Donut Production for " + this.name);
  for (var hour = 0; hour < this.totalHour; hour++) {
   var donutsforHour = this.donutsPerHour();
   this.totalDonuts += donutsforHour;
   this.hourlyDonuts.push(donutsforHour);
===== ==== ======:nth-of-type=================
            $("hour-"+hour+" th:nth-of-type("+this.column+")").html(donutsforHour);
  console.log("   Donuts for hour " + hour + " are " + donutsforHour);
   
  }
  console.log("Total Donuts per day for " + this.name + " is " + this.totalDonuts + "\n");
  
 }
}

var downtownShop = new Shop("Downtown", 8, 43, 4.5, 8, 1);
var capitolhillShop = new Shop("Capitol Hill", 4, 37, 2, 24, 2);
var southlakeunionShop = new Shop("South Lake Union", 9, 23, 6.33, 10, 3);
var wedgewoodShop = new Shop("Wedgewood", 2, 28, 1.25, 7, 4);
var ballardShop = new Shop("Ballard", 8, 58, 3.75, 10, 5);

downtownShop.donutsPerDay();
capitolhillShop.donutsPerDay();
southlakeunionShop.donutsPerDay();
wedgewoodShop.donutsPerDay();
ballardShop.donutsPerDay();


</script>

<html>
<head>
 <title> Donut Hater</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DonutShop2.css">
</head>
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <h1>Donut Hater</h1>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cherry+Cream+Soda' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <h3>Five Locations To Serve You</h3>
     <h3 class = "locations">DOWNTOWN <b class = "stars">&#9733</b> CAPITOL HILL <b>&#9733</b> SOUTH LAKE UNION <b>&#9733</b> WEDGEWOOD <b>&#9733</b> BALLARD</h3>
 

<div id="table">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Code+Pro' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
 <table id="output">
   <table align="center">
    <thead>
   <tr class="header">
    <th scope="col">Hour</th>
    <th scope="col">Downtown</th>
    <th scope="col">Capitol Hill</th>
    <th scope="col">South Lake Union</th>
    <th scope="col">Wedgewood</th>
    <th scope="col">Ballard</th>
   </tr>
   <tr id="hour-0">
    <th scope="row">12:00am</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
   </tr>
   <tr id="hour-1">
    <th scope="row">1:00am</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
   </tr>
   <tr id="hour-2">
    <th scope="row">2:00am</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
   </tr>
   <tr id="hour-3">
    <th scope="row">3:00am</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
   </tr>
   <tr id="hour-4">
    <th scope="row">4:00am</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
   </tr>
   <tr id="hour-5">
    <th scope="row">5:00am</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
   </tr>
   <tr id="hour-6">
    <th scope="row">6:00am</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
   </tr>
   <tr id="hour-7">
    <th scope="row">7:00am</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
   </tr>
   <tr id="hour-8">
    <th scope="row">8:00am</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
   </tr>
   <tr id="hour-9">
    <th scope="row">9:00am</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
   </tr>
   <tr id="hour-10">
    <th scope="row">10:00am</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
   </tr>
   <tr id="hour-11">
    <th scope="row">11:00am</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
   </tr>
   <tr id="hour-12">
    <th scope="row">12:00pm</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
   </tr>
   <tr id="hour-13">
    <th scope="row">1:00pm</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
   </tr>
   <tr id="hour-14">
    <th scope="row">2:00pm</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
   </tr>
   <tr id="hour-15">
    <th scope="row">3:00pm</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
   </tr>
   <tr id="hour-16">
    <th scope="row">4:00pm</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
   </tr>
   <tr id="hour-17">
    <th scope="row">5:00pm</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
   </tr>
   <tr id="hour-18">
    <th scope="row">6:00pm</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
   </tr>
   <tr id="hour-19">
    <th scope="row">7:00pm</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
   </tr>
   <tr id="hour-20">
    <th scope="row">8:00pm</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
   </tr>
   <tr id="hour-21">
    <th scope="row">9:00pm</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
   </tr>
   <tr id="hour-22">
    <th scope="row">10:00pm</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
   </tr>
   <tr id="hour-23">
    <th scope="row">11:00pm</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
   </tr>
   <tr class = "dailyTotal">
    <th scope="row">Daily Total</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
   </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
 </table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="DonutShop.js"></script>

<footer>&copy Donut Hater Donuts &#9733 971.555.9876 &#9733 info@donuthater.com</footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: that's a lot of code to trawl through. You should be putting this.donutsPerHour and this.donutsPerDay on the prototype. Can you simplify the question and pin-point the exact problem with comments?

Comment: console.log(this.column); - and you will see problem. It is undefined and you send it as argument to nth-of-type, but you actually need number.

Comment: I apologize for excessive code snippetry.  I probably could have left off the .css...but I was;t sure where the problem was.  Or wasn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work just change this line:

```
$("#hour-"+hour+" th:nth-child("+(this.displayColumn+1)+")").html(donutsforHour);
```

And add the initialization statements inside an $(function(){}) like this:

```
$(function () {
    downtownShop.donutsPerDay();
    capitolhillShop.donutsPerDay();
    southlakeunionShop.donutsPerDay();
    wedgewoodShop.donutsPerDay();
    ballardShop.donutsPerDay();
});
```

**Edit**: Also note there are many things that are wrong in your code:

- Use TH only for header rows, you should be using TD for the rest of them
- You have two HTML opening tags and, also head opening tag inside the body... review that please :-).

Comment: Thanks.  I think the two opening tags happened when pasting in there.

Comment: That has sense :). Did my changes to your code make it work?

Comment: Only copy the provided code in the same place they are now replacing them

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is quite simple, to identify each box in the table you can assign a different unique id to do it, for example like this

```
   <table>
   <tr><td id='xyz_11'></td><td id='xyz_12'></td><td id='xyz_13'></td></tr>
  <tr><td id='xyz_21'></td><td id='xyz_22'></td><td id='xyz_23'></td></tr>
   </table>
```

Now you have to use unique id to insert the result into it, for example you want to add 3 donuts in the 2nd row of the first column, then you can do like this.

```
 <script>
 document.getElementById('xyz_21').innerHTML=3;
 </script>
```

and likewise you can do this programmatically in javascript for each and every box.